# Visual studio slow down Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, macos-sierra

Visual studio takes 100, 200 or more percentage of CPU. New projects in solution are being created very slowly (2 minutes or more). 
[image]
Visual Studio for Mac Preview, Version: Preview 5 (7.0 build 1659). 
MacBook Pro, Intel Core i5 (2.6 GHz), Memory: 8 GB.

Comment: No process can take more than 100% CPU. 100% means all of it. You should file a bug with Apple.

Comment: Not correct. CPU usage on macOS is not normalized across all cores. That means 100% indicates one core if fully utilized. So a machine with 8 cores can use up to 800% of CPU. Same for a single process with multiple threads. Visual Studio is just performing some bollocks work. Better report that to Microsoft then.

Comment: Same here... if you find some way to fix this, please tell me :)

Comment: I have the same. My laptop just exploding bc of VS.

Comment: Same here, Rider is even worse, my fan is exploding ....